# How do I import specific fields from a shapefile?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1

Using arcpy, how do I import only select fields from a shapefile? Or, if I must import the entire shapefile, how do I delete certain fields after import?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you're importing from?

Comment: @MWrenn I'm not sure what I can include to be more specific. It's a shapefile but I only want some fields imported.

Comment: Imported to where? Do you just want to delete fields from an existing shapefile? Do you want only certain fields displayed in ArcMap when you add it to a project/MXD?

Comment: @DenaliHardtail Could you just make a copy of the shapefile and on the copy, delete any fields not wanted, and import that your location (which can all be done via arcpy)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will want to use [Feature Class To Feature Class (Conversion)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001200000020000000) to copy the feature class or shapefile.  Make sure to specify which fields are included in the output feature class using [FieldMappings (arcpy)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018z00000078000000).

Alternatively, use [Feature Class To Feature Class (Conversion)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001200000020000000) or [Copy Features (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000035000000) to make a copy of your features, then use [Delete Field (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000004n000000) to remove the fields you do not need.

Here is an example from the Delete Field documentation:

```
# Import system modules
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

# Set environment settings
env.workspace = "C:/data"

# Set local variables
inFeatures = "accident.dbf"
outFeatureClass = "C:/output/new_accident.dbf"
dropFields = ["STREET_NAM", "LABEL", "CLASS"]

# Execute CopyFeatures to make a new copy of the feature class
#  Use CopyRows if you have a table
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(inFeatures, outFeatureClass)

# Execute DeleteField
arcpy.DeleteField_management(outFeatureClass, dropFields)
```

Comment: `FieldMappings` is probably the "right" way to do it, but I've always found `DeleteField` to be much easier :)

Comment: Agreed, @Erica.  FieldMappings are not easy to use.  I also prefer to use Delete Fields.